# Why is csv.reader not considered a class?

Tags: python

From my understanding, an object is an instance of a class. So since csv.reader creates a reader object, I thought that it would be considered a class. I'm pretty new to this, so it would be helpful if someone could clarify this for me.

Comment: `math.sqrt` creates a number.  Is `sqrt` a class?

Comment: Not everything that returns an object is a class. Indeed, *most things that return objects aren't classes*. `abs(-3)` returns an `int` object, but it isn't a class. It is a plain function.

Comment: @jwodder: sqrt would just be a function that's part of the math module, correct?

Comment: @Sharon yes. Similarly, `csv.reader` is a function that belongs to the `csv` module. Under the hood, it returns an object of a class that is not exposed to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If something is an object, it's generally not a class
It's like with animal species.

The dog named Cujo is of the species Dog, but Cujo isn't the species (category) itself.
You can create a dog e.g. by:

```
dog = Dog ('Cujo')
```

I can have the class Dinosaur, but there are no living objects of that class around anymore.

Not only classes can return objects. I can have a function as follows:

```
def dog_factory (name):
    return Dog (name)
```

To create a dog with that, you can state:

```
dog = dog_factory ('Cujo')
```

While Dog is a class, dog_factory is just a function.
It uses the class to create a dog.

If you ask for the class, using `type (dog)`,
you'll see that dog is of class Dog, not of class dog_factory.

Don't be confused by the situation in JavaScript, if you happen to know that.
Truly class-based languages like C++, Java, C# and Python are quite different,
and in my view less contorted.

Answer (score 2):

From the [PEP 305](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0305/#reading-csv-files):

> CSV readers are created with the reader factory function:

```
obj = reader(iterable [, dialect='excel']
             [optional keyword args])
```

So `csv.reader` itself is technically a *function*, and not a class.

You might think it would make more sense if `csv.reader` was a class, and `isinstance(my_reader, csv.reader)` returned `True`, and I'd agree with you.  That's how `csv.DictReader` does it:

```
>>> import io, csv
>>> reader = csv.DictReader(io.StringIO())
>>> isinstance(reader, csv.DictReader)
True
```

Unfortunately, the CPython code which defines the reader type and exposes it to the `csv.py` module was not carefully designed to be consistent with such conventions. Instead, [`csv` imports the name `reader` from a `_csv` module](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/93c5a5df8ea118f6e4a153a7c8cccd65a5ff8bff/Lib/csv.py#L7), which is distributed as compiled code from an .so (binary) file. Historically, [the all lowercase name referred to a C type](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2009-March/086646.html), which explains the name `_csv.reader` instead of `_csv.Reader`.

Internally, a csv reader is an instance of the `type(_csv.reader(...))` class, and that class itself is not exposed. So if you want to type-check it, you would need to do something hacky like this:

```
>>> import io, csv
>>> csv.Reader = type(csv.reader(io.StringIO()))
>>> isinstance(csv.reader(io.StringIO()), csv.Reader)
True
```

There's no particular reason the library developers couldn't have made the class public and called it `csv.Reader`, but that's not what happened. The `csv` module is about 15 years old at this time, and it predates the cleanup of Python's object model, when the naming conventions for types and classes had time to become better established.

Unfortunately, changing the interface from a `csv.reader` factory function into a `csv.Reader` class would break backwards compatibility.

Comment: Eh, but `type(csv.reader)` is function, and `type(defaultdict)` is `type`.

Comment: It may try to tell you that, but it is a dict subclass.

Comment: Yes, of course. Because *dict is a type* and so is *defaultdict*. however, `csv.reader` is *not a type*, it is more like an alternate constructor, the type of the objects it returns is `<class '_csv.reader'>`, which isn't exposed, and that type doesn't allow you to make instances of it directly. I did not downvote, btw

Comment: `csv.reader` being implemented in C has nothing to do with it not being a class.  It may have something to do with its name being all-lowercase as your answer implies, but that's not what the question is about.

Comment: Sure, that isn't the point I'm making. Sorry, I went back and edited that last comment to elaborate a bit.

Comment: `csv.reader` is a function that returns an instance of the class `_csv.reader`, but that is implementation detail.  If you want to insist on calling it an "alternate constructor", you may, but that's all smoke and mirrors.  The simple and correct way to think of it is as a class with a weird name due to historical convention.

Comment: I don't think this answer is all that bad... It isn't low hanging fruit, but I can quite follow Wim's line of thinking. So I'll upvote.

Comment: @JacquesdeHooge: The answer is outright wrong. You should not upvote wrong answers simply because you can follow their line of thinking; you should downvote them because they're wrong.

Comment: You can upvote/downvote all you like.  By the way, I have actually asked **this same question** to CPython developers about a year ago (in person) when I was curious about the fact.  I've just reproduced here what they answered me.

Comment: Why are you talking about naming conventions, anyway? `defaultdict` is an actual class despite being implemented in C. `csv.reader` doesn't need to be a factory function just because it's in C, and they could have broken backward compatibility in Python 3.

Comment: Because I think part of the confusion stems from the fact that `csv.Reader` would have been more in line with Python's naming convention.  You may as well ask why the `_csv.reader` is not named `_csv.Reader` (and the reason is a dumb historical convention).  CPython don't break backwards compat except for very good reasons, and this was not a good enough reason.

Comment: (I don't trust your memory of an in-person conversation from a year ago with unnamed developers who may not have had anything to do with the `csv` module. There are far too many ways one of you could have miscommunicated, misunderstood, or misremembered something. If the explanation doesn't make sense, I don't buy it.)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga  If `csv.reader` is an *alternate constructor*, then what is the main constructor?

Comment: @user2357112  A bit of a frosty attitude, but fine.  Could you explain which part of this answer is outright wrong, or add your own answer?

Comment: Own answer added. I see you've cleaned up most of the things I considered outright wrong since my last comment.

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to word it in a way to appease those downvoters.  My real answer remains "because it's old and it was C", but I've put that between the lines now.

Comment: Related: the weird naming inconsistencies in `collections` (`defaultdict`, `OrderedDict`, `deque`, `Counter`...).  [*Traditionally, the all lowercase name referred to a C type*](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2009-March/086646.html).

Comment: @jwodder  `csv.reader` being implemented in C has *everything* to do with it not being a class.  And if it were rewritten today, it *would* be a class, but nobody could be bothered to do that because there are better things to do and "if it ain't broke, don't fix it".

Comment: @wim alternate constructor was the wrong term. Factory function would be better.

Answer (score 2):

Not everything that creates an object is a class. *Most* callables that create objects aren't classes, and every callable returns an object unless it doesn't return anything at all (by throwing an exception, for example). For example,

```
def f():
    return []
```

creates and returns a list object, but it's not a class.

As for why `csv.reader` specifically wasn't written to be a class, that seems to be an artifact of the historical development of the `csv` module. The original [PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0305/) proposing the module says `reader` should be a function:

> CSV readers are created with the reader factory function

but that just shifts the question from "why is `reader` not a class" to "why does the PEP say it shouldn't be a class", and the PEP doesn't give a rationale.

One possibility is to allow the factory function to return multiple reader types, although that doesn't seem to have ever been explored. Another hypothesis is that the module descends from code so old it *had* to use a factory function.

`csv.reader` returns instances of a reader type [written in C](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/_csv.c), and the CSV PEP suggests that the code may be based on an [earlier C module](http://www.object-craft.com.au/projects/csv/) so old it predates [type-class unification](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.2/descrintro/). Back before type-class unification, types written in C *couldn't* be called directly. You *had* to write a factory function to create instances of C types. This even extended to built-in types like `list` and `int`; back then, names like `list` and `int` were instead factory functions that created list and int objects, rather than referring to the types themselves.

In Python 2.2, type-class unification made C types callable, but code designed with the earlier system in mind would still have factory functions and not necessarily any compelling reason to get rid of them.